# sqlalchemy query from hybrid_property with relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to figure out how to get a query evaluate the hybrid_property instead of the db column values. From my understanding the only way to achieve this behavior is using an `expression` which replicates what the getter is doing.

This is my model:

```
class QuizSettings(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = "quiz_settings"
    test_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("tests.id"), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    test = relationship("Test")
    _due_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=True, name="due_at")
    
    @hybrid_property
    def due_at(self) -> Optional[datetime]:
        if self._due_at == DEFAULT_DATE:
            return self.test.due_at
        return self._due_at

    @due_at.setter
    def due_at(self, due_at: Optional[datetime]) -> None:
        if self.test and due_at == self.test.due_at:
            self._due_at = DEFAULT_DATE
        else:
            self._due_at = due_at
```

The query:

```
session.query(QuizSettings).filter(QuizSettings.due_at <= current_datetime).all()
```

I  have tried to add the following expression:

```
@classmethod
def _due_at_expression(cls, test, quiz_due_at, default_date):
    test_due_at = test.due_at

    return case(
        (
            (quiz_due_at == default_date, func.coalesce(test_due_at, default_date)),
        ),
        else_=quiz_due_at
    )

@due_at.expression
def due_at(cls):
    selected_test = select(Test).where(cls.test_id == Test.id).correlate(cls).as_scalar()
    return cls._due_at_expression(selected_test, cls._due_at, DEFAULT_DATE)
```

However it looks like I'm doing something wrong in the select clause to get the `test` because instead of a `Test` instance the `selected_test` is a `Select` object

> AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'due_at'

The alternative would be to get all guiz settings from the query and then iterate to the QuizSettings instance and check the condition with python, but this is not the correct approach because all scenarios will have to be handled this way...